# Values in View and split a string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

First off, I use this to get some kind of data from the database

```
string Query = "SELECT * FROM dbo.Person WHERE PersonId != @ID";
SqlParameter Parameter = new SqlParameter("@ID", ID);
IEnumerable<???> = db.Person.SqlQuery(Query, Parameter).ToList();
```

What should I return my result as a list of?

---

Then I just pass it along into my View right?

```
return View(???);
```

---

Should I edit my data before sending it to the view, or should I edit it in the View?

Because one of my values in the database is a value separated by semicolons

```
value1;value2;value3
```

So I want to separate them, but how can I separate them, and if I separate in my controller, then how do I pass multiple values to the View?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result can be anything as long as the type your return in the controller, is also implemented as Model in the View. The View receives this type. So `return View(IEnumerable<Person>)`  should be fine.

I would suggest you edit the data in the model, but technically it doesn't matter. You can edit your data while looping through it in the view.

Comment: Ok, so I got it into my View now like
@model IEnumerable<CV.Models.Cv>

How do I display a value?
And how do I manage to split a string?

Comment: Display a value with @HTML.DisplayFor(var)
Split a string with myString.Split(',')